# How to deal with large data while using feign client

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-feign

I am new to Spring Cloud and I am using 4 databases to make a web application and so as many microservices.

SOME EXPLANATION ABOUT MY APPLICATION:

So, now 1st DB is Account database where users are stored in a way to satisfy manager,employee relationship (like parent_id column in account table).

account_table(id,email,parent_id)

So, in 2nd database is task where task of employees get stored.

task_table(id,task_name,desc,assigned_user_id);

REQUIREMENT:

Requirement is to fetch all tasks of employees under one manager.

WHAT I AM DOING RIGHT NOW:

So, what I do here is I fetch all employees under that manager using manager's user_id using feign client and then find all those tasks which are assigned to those employee's user_id and everything works fine.

PROBLEM:

When employees under one manager gets a little bit large such as more than 50, final service for getting all tasks get too much slow (1.5min).

PROBABLE SOLUTION FROM MY SIDE:

I am thinking of passing all childEmployee's userId under one userId in auth token. So, this way, i don't have to use feign request and hence services will be faster. But, not sure this is the best solution.

Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne I believe yes. I have replicated some specific information of one DB to another DB in case of join between two tables of two different DBs. I did this after reading some articles on Data replication in microservices.